# Is there a way to export from an SQL Server by using the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I know you can right-click on the database, and go to tasks, and export the data, but I need to know  if there is a way to export the data directly from the query, without those steps. I have a program that will pull the data for that day at the end of the day, and I am trying to have the program automatically export the data every day to a file outside of the SQL server, so that I could open the data using excel, or something similar. Is this possible?

Comment: depending on how large your data is, I usually do this with an ODBC connection & Python. You can either write your raw query as a string or do your wrangling in Pandas then export to your desired location using the pathlib or OS library. you can set this on a server side cron job to automate it - I ran across the same problem and found this solution quite elegant. Again if your data is "big data" think 10m rows x10cols + this might not be suitable.

Comment: Would the [bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) help?

Comment: BCP is the way to go, it should do everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BCP to enter code which will export the the results of a query to a file:

```
bcp "select * from tableA' queryout" c:\files\test25.txt -c -T
```

or you can use SQLCMD or from TSQL you can insert into a openrowset.

Comment: Is bcp a standard command for SQL server? Everytime I type it into my code, it returns "Incorrect syntax near 'bcp'", like it doesn't recognize it as a command

Comment: nevermind i was trying to use bcp in SQL rather than in the command prompt